# Read input from console in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, console

I want to write a simple A+B program in ruby, but I have no idea how to work with the console.

Answer (score 253, accepted):

Are you talking about `gets`?

```
puts "Enter A"
a = gets.chomp
puts "Enter B"
b = gets.chomp
c = a.to_i + b.to_i
puts c
```

Something like that?

#### Update

`Kernel.gets` tries to read the params found in `ARGV` and only asks to console if not `ARGV` found. To force to read from console even if `ARGV` is not empty use `STDIN.gets`

Comment: I have a conflict with this solution: `Kernel.gets` try to read the files found in `ARGV` and only asks to console if not `ARGV` found. To force to read from console even if `ARGV` is not empty use `STDIN.gets`.

Comment: `a.to_i` and `b.to_i` could be better

Comment: is `gets` blocking? If not, is there any substitute which is blocking?

Comment: @fguillen that's a great answer and shouldn't be hidden in comments. Could you perhaps make it an answer, please? Thanks!

Comment: @Yar thanks for the suggestion, I've added an _update_ to the answer itself.

Comment: great, thanks for helping out, @fguillen and for knowing that. I've used it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remote/20081966#20081966

And will probably use it a lot more now that I know it.

Answer (score 31):

you can also pass the parameters through the command line. Command line arguments are stores in the array ARGV. so ARGV[0] is the first number and ARGV[1] the second number

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

first_number = ARGV[0].to_i
second_number = ARGV[1].to_i

puts first_number + second_number
```

and you call it like this

```
% ./plus.rb 5 6
==> 11
```

Answer (score 11):

There are many ways to take input from the users. I personally like
    using the method gets. When you use gets, it gets the **string**
    that you typed, and that includes the **ENTER** key that you pressed
    to end your input.

```
name = gets
"mukesh\n"
```

> You can see this in **irb**; type this and you will see the \n, which is the “newline” character that the ENTER key produces: 
>   Type `name = gets` you will see somethings like `"mukesh\n"`
>   You can get rid of pesky **newline** character using **chomp** method.

The chomp method gives you back the string, but without the terminating newline. Beautiful chomp method life saviour.

```
name = gets.chomp
"mukesh"
```

You can also use terminal to read the input. **ARGV** is a constant defined in the **Object** **class**. It is an instance of the **Array class** and has access to all the array methods. Since it’s an array, even though it’s a constant, its elements can be modified and cleared with no trouble. By default, Ruby captures all the command line arguments passed to a Ruby program (split by spaces) when the command-line binary is invoked and stores them as strings in the **ARGV array**.

When written inside your Ruby program, **ARGV** will take take a command line command that looks like this:

```
test.rb hi my name is mukesh
```

and create an array that looks like this:

```
["hi", "my", "name", "is", "mukesh"]
```

But, if I want to passed limited input then we  can use something like this.

```
test.rb 12 23
```

and use those input like this in your program:

```
a = ARGV[0]
b = ARGV[1]
```

Answer (score 5):

if you want to hold the arguments from Terminal, try the following code:

```
A = ARGV[0].to_i
B = ARGV[1].to_i

puts "#{A} + #{B} = #{A + B}"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make interactive console:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "readline"
addends = []
while addend_string = Readline.readline("> ", true)
  addends << addend_string.to_i
  puts "#{addends.join(' + ')} = #{addends.sum}"
end
```

Usage (assuming you put above snippet into `summator` file in current directory):

```
chmod +x summator
./summator
> 1
1 = 1
> 2
1 + 2 = 3
```

Use `Ctrl + D` to exit