# simple if else statement unit conversion cm and in

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, if-statement

For some reason this code always multiplies `b` (2.54) by `unit_number`, regardless of whether I put enter "cm" or "in":

```
puts "Welcome to my unit conversion calculator. This calculator can convert
between Centimeters and Inches. If you could like to convert Centimeters to Inches, write: in. If you would like to convert Inches to centimeters, write: cm."

unit = gets.to_s

puts " how many of your unit would you like to convert"
unit_number = gets.to_f

a = 0.39370079
b = 2.54

if unit == 'in'      
  puts "your conversion is: #{ (unit_number * a)}"    
else unit == 'cm'
  puts "your conversion is: #{ (unit_number * b)}"
end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please improve your question by posting some [properly formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) code you've applied to the problem, all **relevant** error messages exactly as they appear, and whatever samples you're testing against. Also, please include a properly-formatted sample of your **expected output** so folks understand the results you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi sorry but I am confused about this question as well, are you looking for a solution like this. [read input from console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556280/read-input-from-console-in-ruby)

Comment: Presumably, `gets` will equal either `cm` or `in`. If this is true, then `gets.to_f` will __always__ equal `0.0`. Am I missing something?

Comment: You don't need to type `gets.to_s`. `gets` is short for get string, which means that you're going to be getting a string anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gets` will capture the stdin input including the trailing new line (enter), so `unit` won't be `'cm'` and instead will be `"cm\n"`. You will need to remove the trailing `"\n"` using `chomp`:

```
unit = gets.chomp
```

You don't need to call `to_s` to the return value of `gets` because it is already a `String`, and the `else` statement should be `elsif unit == 'cm'` or `else if unit == 'cm'`.

Comment: thank you very much. for some reason the programs runs fine when using just: else and doesn't run when using: elseif. Ill just leave it how it is. thanks again

Comment: [`strip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-strip) may be better than `chomp`.

Comment: `chomp` is best in this situations are it more clearly indicates that you are trying to remove trailing whitespace. More importantly, `chomp` automatically handles both Unix-style `\n` line endings and Windows-style `\r\n` line endings (which would require explicit separate handing via `strip`).

Answer (score 1):

Your conditional invokes an `else` statement, when what you *actually* need is an **`elsif`** statement:

```
elsif unit == 'cm'
```

Basically, what you currently have is a situation where the first of your conditions (i.e., `if unit == 'in'`) is not being met (see [Pablo B's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18689824/1086529) for reasons why). However, the second condition *is* met because it's an `else` statement. Since the first condition is always false, the `else` condition will always be true.

If, instead, you invoke an `elsif` statement, the conditional will first check whether `unit == 'in'`; if it's not, then it checks whether `unit == 'cm'`. If neither are true, then the condition will return `nil`.

Comment: To clarify, `else unit == 'cm'` is two statements. To see the logic flow, put the `else` on a line by itself. Then it will execute two statements: the first will be the expression `unit == 'cm'`, which will evaluate to `false` and simply be ignored, as it's not part of another expression. Then the `puts` will execute. You can use `else if` or the combination `elseif`. You still need to fix the trailing `\n` issue mentioned by @Pablo B. as well.

Comment: Very right. I understand that `else unit == 'cm'` is two statements. I'm suggesting that the poster has conflated `else unit == 'cm'` with `elseif unit == 'cm'`.

Comment: @nonocut, what do you mean?

Comment: You need to use `elsif` instead of `elseif`

Comment: While that's true, an alternative syntax is `else if`, FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

I know exactly how do you feel. Debugging is a pain. @akhanubis already pointed you towards `#chomp` method needed to process your `gets` return value. While I assume that you wrote your code for didactic purposes, if you ever need to [convert physical units for real](https://rubygems.org/gems/sy), just install *sy* gem. After `gem install sy`, you can:

```
require 'sy/imperial'

7.5.inch.in :cm
#=> 19.05
42.cm.in :inch
#=> 16.5354
```