# Java-like .hasNext() method in Ruby?

Tags: java, ruby

Is there a similar syntax to Java's `.hasNext()` method in Ruby? I've been trying to get inputs in one line and then making it as integers and getting the absolute value.

Comment: It’s easier to answer if you show us your code and sample input and expected/actual output.

Comment: You mean the `gets` method? Like used [`here`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6556370/1860929)?

Comment: What do you mean by syntax. Methods in ruby look like Java's `foo.bar(baz, quux)`

Comment: In Ruby, you don't need the equivalent of `Iterator`'s `hasNext()`.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to see if there are more elements left in an iteration. Ruby's equivalent to that is [`peek`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-peek):

From the docs:

> Returns the next object in the enumerator, but doesn’t move the internal position forward. If the position is already at the end, StopIteration is raised.

But, in Ruby we usually rely on `each` or `map` to walk an iterable collection. There's no "figuring out" whether there's another element remaining, because Ruby does that for us.

Answer (score -2):

ansh0l is right, gets is the most likely equivalent to hasNext() assuming that you're reading from the keyboard or any other I/O stream.

Comment: `gets` is not the same thing as `hasNext()`. At all.

Comment: @MarkThomas: The examples that I found for hasNext dealt with the input stream in particular.  Since this question also dealt with receiving input from the command line there seemed to be greater correspondence than you suggest.